# How to create stepper in Reactjs?

Tags: css, reactjs

I was trying to create stepper in Reactjs but while applying css properties it throws error in span for css properties

I want to create multi-step form so i thought of creating stepper
[Code Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-kirch-iqji3?file=/src/App.js)

Here is css code

```
$md-blue-500: #2196f3;

.stepper-number {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  background-color: white;
  color: grey;

  span:after {
    width: 999em;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 40px;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    content: "";
  }

  span:first-child {
    &:after {
      left: 50%;
    }
  }

  span:last-child {
    &:after {
      right: 50%;
      left: auto;
    }
  }

  &.active {
    border: 2px solid $md-blue-500;
    color: white;
    background-color: $md-blue-500;
  }
}
```

Comment: "It throws error somehow"; Are you talking about the `Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` error? Please state the actual problem!

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are trying to use sass in a plain .css file rather than .scss. That is why the file has errors.

Comment: I didn't downvote @AlexGilliott  and the problem is with css file as I don't think using unique "key" prop would solve css issue

Comment: Fair enough, edited to remove that part. The file extension is still probably the issue, could you confirm?